# objective-c adding UILabel to center

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, theos

hi i'm begginer in objective-c and i want to learn how i can make UILabel in center of screen

this is my code:

**XXRootViewController.h**

```
@interface XXRootViewController : UIViewController{

UILabel *title; } @end
```

**XXRootViewController.m**

```
#import "XXRootViewController.h"

@implementation XXRootViewController {
NSMutableArray *_objects;
}

- (void)loadView {
[super loadView];

self.view = [[[UIView alloc]
    initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]]
autorelease];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300,200,400,200)];
title.text = @"This is Sasuke's first app :)";
[self.view addSubview:title];
}

@end
```

Comment: i am not test this code but try title.center = self.view.center

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code i make some changes in you code**

```
self.view = [[UIView alloc]
                  initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 50,200)];
title.text = @"This is Sasuke's first app :)";
title.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
title.center = self.view.center;
[self.view addSubview:title];
```

Answer (score 1):

Has Hardik Thakkar said, the best way would be to use the center method. That way, even if your label would grow, it will always be centred.

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300,200,400,200)];
label.text = @"something";
label.center = self.view.center; (this should always be you superview)
```

Now, even if your label is bigger than the size you were expecting, it will always be centred

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set frame in center of the screen ... 
change your one line code with it -

```
title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 - 200,self.view.frame.size.height/2 - 100,400,200)];
```

now your label is shown in the center of screen .. This will help you change the frame according to your use...